# How to restore the ownership of a folder to "Trusted installer" using silent command line

Tags: ntfs

Please could any one let me know the silent command to restore the owner ship to "Trusted installer" as a default owner. steps i performed is :

1- `TAKEOWN /R /F "C:\Program files"`  (SUCCESS &  now i could see owner is SYSTEM)
2 - `cacls "c:\Program files" /T /E /G ProgFiles:W` (ProgFiles is the local group)  - SUCCESS

Now here i tried below to restore the ownership:

`icacls "C:\Program files" /setowner "NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller" /t /c`

( It gave me message saying , successfully processed 897 files, failed processing 1134 files. (and still i could see SYSTEM as owner and not Trusted installed).

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, I only needed to change the root. This did it

```sh
takeown /f C:\
icacls C:\ /setowner "NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have not found an easy way from cmd.exe, but this snip will force ownership back to TrustedInstaller from Powershell.

Force_Ownership.ps1

```
$PATHNAME = "C:\Temp"

Function Enable-Privilege 
{
 param([ValidateSet("SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege", "SeAuditPrivilege", "SeBackupPrivilege",
   "SeChangeNotifyPrivilege", "SeCreateGlobalPrivilege", "SeCreatePagefilePrivilege",
   "SeCreatePermanentPrivilege", "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege", "SeCreateTokenPrivilege",
   "SeDebugPrivilege", "SeEnableDelegationPrivilege", "SeImpersonatePrivilege", "SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege",
   "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege", "SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege", "SeLoadDriverPrivilege",
   "SeLockMemoryPrivilege", "SeMachineAccountPrivilege", "SeManageVolumePrivilege",
   "SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege", "SeRelabelPrivilege", "SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege",
   "SeRestorePrivilege", "SeSecurityPrivilege", "SeShutdownPrivilege", "SeSyncAgentPrivilege",
   "SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege", "SeSystemProfilePrivilege", "SeSystemtimePrivilege",
   "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege", "SeTcbPrivilege", "SeTimeZonePrivilege", "SeTrustedCredManAccessPrivilege",
   "SeUndockPrivilege", "SeUnsolicitedInputPrivilege")]$Privilege,
  $ProcessId = $pid,
  [Switch]$Disable)

   $Definition = @'
 using System;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

 public class AdjPriv
 {
  [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
  internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall,
   ref TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);

  [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
  internal static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr h, int acc, ref IntPtr phtok);
  [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  internal static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string host, string name, ref long pluid);
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
  internal struct TokPriv1Luid
  {
   public int Count;
   public long Luid;
   public int Attr;
  }

  internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
  internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_DISABLED = 0x00000000;
  internal const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
  internal const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;
  public static bool EnablePrivilege(long processHandle, string privilege, bool disable)
  {
   bool retVal;
   TokPriv1Luid tp;
   IntPtr hproc = new IntPtr(processHandle);
   IntPtr htok = IntPtr.Zero;
   retVal = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
   tp.Count = 1;
   tp.Luid = 0;
   if(disable)
   {
    tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_DISABLED;
   }
   else
   {
    tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
   }
   retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref tp.Luid);
   retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
   return retVal;
  }
 }
'@


 $ProcessHandle = (Get-Process -id $ProcessId).Handle
 $type = Add-Type $definition -PassThru
 $type[0]::EnablePrivilege($processHandle, $Privilege, $Disable)

}


[System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]$TrustedInstaller = "NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller"
$ACL = Get-Acl $PATHNAME
$ACL.SetOwner($TrustedInstaller)
Enable-Privilege SeRestorePrivilege  
Set-Acl -Path $PATHNAME -AclObject $ACL
```

Comment: Note: Trusted Installer's Well-Known SID   `S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271478464`

Comment: I wonder if Helge Klien's Set-ACL might not be an acceptable cmd.exe alternative.  Requires 3rd party app -  http://helgeklein.com/setacl/